# Angular Xeditable grid set current date as default date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, x-editable

I'm using [Angular Xeditable grid](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row).Could you tell me how to set the curent date as default date on the calendar control which I have used within the above grid ? Thanks.

```
    <tr ng-repeat="comment in vm.comments track by $index">
                <td>
                    <span editable-bsdate="comment.date" e-uib-datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" e-ng-click="opened = !opened" e-is-open="opened" e-name="date" e-form="commentForm" onbeforesave="vm.checkValidity($data)" e-required>
                        {{ comment.date | date:'MM-dd-yyyy' }}
                    </span>
                </td>
      </tr>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.addComment()">Add</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is :)

**Js**

```
vm.addComment = function () {
      vm.comments.push(vm.comment = {
         date: new Date()
    });
 };
```